# "npm -g yarn" gives "permission denied, symlink..." but the proper permissions do exists

Tags: linux, npm, yarnpkg

I need to install yarn without sudo. I do this:

```
$ npm install -g yarn
```

and I get this:

```
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall symlink
npm ERR! path ../lib/node_modules/yarn/bin/yarn.js
npm ERR! dest /usr/bin/yarn
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink '../lib/node_modules/yarn/bin/yarn.js' -> '/usr/bin/yarn'
npm ERR!  [OperationalError: EACCES: permission denied, symlink '../lib/node_modules/yarn/bin/yarn.js' -> '/usr/bin/yarn'] {
npm ERR!   cause: [Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink '../lib/node_modules/yarn/bin/yarn.js' -> '/usr/bin/yarn'] {
[.........]
```

But:

```
ls -al /usr/lib/node_modules/

drwxr-xr-x  5 user1 user1  4096 Sep 15 05:13 .
drwxr-xr-x 63 root  root  32768 Sep 14 15:18 ..
drwxr-xr-x  9 user1 user1  4096 Sep 14 14:48 node-gyp
drwxr-xr-x  9 user1 user1  4096 Sep 15 04:22 npm
drwxr-xr-x  7 user1 user1  4096 Sep 14 14:48 semver
```

And

```
$ ls -ald /usr/lib/node_modules/
drwxr-xr-x 5 user1 user1 4096 Sep 15 05:13 /usr/lib/node_modules/
```

Why and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your config folder must be owned by root, which creates several permissions issue. Changing it to the current user will solve it

$USER:$GROUP -> gives the current login user and the group. in the terminal you can try to echo $USER echo $GROUP to know its value. By this command, it will change to the value present in $USER. The same applies for the group too.

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$GROUP ~/.npm
sudo chown -R $USER:$GROUP ~/.config
```

now try all your commands

replication of https://github.com/bower/bower/issues/2262

Comment: what's `$GROUP`?

Comment: `drwxr-xr-x 5 user1 user1 4096 Sep 15 05:13 /usr/lib/node_modules/` the second user1 is the entry for group.In linux a group is a collection of users. The main purpose of the groups is to define a set of privileges like read, write, or execute permission for a given resource that can be shared among the users within the group. Users can be added to an existing group to utilize the privileges it grants.

Comment: Did it worked for you?

Comment: I'm asking what value does a `GROUP` have to have in this case. The same question for `USER`

Comment: $USER:$GROUP -> gives the current login user and the group. in terminal you can try echo $USER echo $GROUP to know its value. By this command it will change to the value present in $USER. same applies for group too. 
the value should be the user who is running command `npm install -g yarn` which i think it should be user1

Comment: what's terminal?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221491/discussion-between-jatin-mehrotra-and-kosmosu).

Comment: Nooooooooooooooo. Here!

Comment: its command prompt, in linux language its called terminal., if it helped you please accept it as a solution to your question, so that in the future it may help others.

Comment: what's linux?....

Comment: This solution did not work for me

Comment: Thank you but I have this err and yet my config folder was owned properly.